# SQL (MySQL): Match first letter of any word in a string?

Tags: sql, mysql

(Note: This is for MySQL's SQL, not SQL Server.)

I have a database column with values like "abc def GHI JKL". I want to write a WHERE clause that includes a case-insensitive test for any word that begins with a specific letter. For example, that example would test true for the letters a,c,g,j because there's a 'word' beginning with each of those letters. The application is for a search that offers to find records that have only words beginning with the specified letter. Also note that there is not a fulltext index for this table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using REGEXP opearator:

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `body` REGEXP '[[:<:]][acgj]'
```

It returns records where column body contains words starting with a,c,g or i (case insensitive)

Be aware though: this is not a very good idea if you expect any heavy load (not using index - it scans every row!)

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. I've added a USE INDEX. Guess it's better to scan the entire index than scan the entire table.

Comment: Beware: This will not work for Multi-byte characters
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `LIKE` operation. If your words are space-separated, append a space to the start of the string to give the first word a chance to match:

```
SELECT
  StringCol
FROM
  MyTable
WHERE
  ' ' + StringCol LIKE '% ' + MyLetterParam + '%'
```

Where `MyLetterParam` could be something like this:

```
'[acgj]'
```

To look for more than a space as a word separator, you can expand that technique. The following would treat TAB, CR, LF, space and NBSP as word separators.

```
WHERE
  ' ' + StringCol LIKE '%['+' '+CHAR(9)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(160)+'][acgj]%'
```

This approach has the nice touch of being standard SQL. It would work unchanged across the major SQL dialects.

Comment: IT should be CONCAT(' ',StringCol), some mysql versions doesn't sum well the chars with + operator

Comment: I didn't know - thanks for the hint! (Can you also add some context? Which versions/situations can be problematic?)

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Pattern Matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) and [Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html) sections of the MySQL Reference Manual.